# How can we update the fields of a redux form by dispatching an action

Tags: redux, state, redux-form

i have two fields with redux form. I have a refresh button through which i update my state through an action. This refresh button updates three text values. My problem is that i must refresh the field values of my form. How to update the state of my redux form. I'm thinking of using a selector like this:

```
export const formsState = state => state.get('form');
```

Then i will create a reducer which is taking the formstate and updates it with

```
update formsState 
        .update('order', action.payload.price);
```

But i dont think this is the best solution. Do have some better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you refresh button send an action which will update your store via the reducer.

In order to update your component I would suggest to use a react containers usinng [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Use the following function:

`store.getState()` to get your state.

`store.dispatch()` to dispatch your action.

Comment: Yes but how i will update the state of my redux form?

Comment: I know how to update my store via actions. But redux-form has a formReducer. By dispatching an action i want to update the formState